# Why is RxJs pipe filter allowing non true values through?

Tags: filter, promise, pipe, observable, rxjs6

I'm learning Rxjs observables and trying to figure out why this following filter isn't working as I expected.

My question is with the following setup, why is the code in the .then() block executed even when classA's var1 value is not true?  Shouldn't the filter function only allow true values through to be turned into a promise and the rest gets discarded?

```
Class A:
   var1: boolean;

Class B:
   var2$: observable<boolean> = of(classA.var1)
   
   FilterObservableValue(){
        this.var2$.pipe(
                filter( x => x === true)
            )
            .toPromise()
            .then(() => {
                //Why is Code here executed when value of var2$ is false? Shouldn't filter function filter out non true values?
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter operator is working well, The problem is with the **toPromise**:

*You have to know that it's the natural behavior of Promises. so even if it will not receive any value it will not reject and it will be fulfilled with an **undefined** value*

Comment: I was under the understanding that the pipe filter will only let true values through to get turned into promises with the above implementation, is that not correct?  

basically the intention here is to read an observable<boolean>, wait for it to turn true before proceeding, once it turns true, do some logic, and then continue with the rest of the code execution.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: of(false, false, true).pipe(
  filter(x => !!x),
  take(1),
  tap(s => console.log(s) /* code executed only when value is true */))
  .toPromise().then(x => console.log(x))